# Samsung NP N150 sp0gin notebook overheating

Tags: cpu, temperature

temperature is more than normal in my samsung np n150 jp0gin netbook running xubuntu11.04, it reports 64 degrees in normal state and 70 degrees while listening music on grooveshark or installing some software via software centre. can anybody help resolving this problem?

moreover xubuntu 11.04 sucks battery more fast than windows 7.on ubuntu battery lasts only 4 hours while in windows 7 it usually lasts 7 or 8 hours.

kernel version:2.6.38-10-generic

Comment: Processor temps vary depending on processor usage.  that affects the temperature.

Comment: 74 degrees is not normal temperature when the critical temperature for it is 90 degrees and it happens while browsing internet whatabout the other processor intensive tasks. Moreover this overheating problem sucking my new battery fast and all my keyboard is hot.I got same answers from ubuntu irc support.nobody is trying to understand the problem.finally found this article http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux_2638_aspm&num=1 about aspm. after applying the patch there's some decrease in temp.Now it hasn't gone to 74 degrees yet.

Comment: and also this link helped too http://www.techytalk.info/linux-kernel-2-6-38-2-6-39-power-regression-workaround/

Comment: How did you determine the critical temp of 90 degrees C?

Comment: installed lm-sensors. in its output it shows that. Thanks anyway the above asmp patch solved the problem with battery life and overheating issue.

Comment: If you have solved your question can you mark as solved please?

Answer (score 2):

OP answered question in comment

74 degrees is not normal temperature when the critical temperature for it is 90 degrees and it happens while browsing internet whatabout the other processor intensive tasks. Moreover this overheating problem sucking my new battery fast and all my keyboard is hot.I got same answers from ubuntu irc support.nobody is trying to understand the problem.finally found this article [phoronix.com/… about aspm](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux_2638_aspm&num=1). after applying the patch there's some decrease in temp.Now it hasn't gone to 74 degrees yet.